# Leetcode java code array output limited for no reason

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

[output(supposed to be the stdout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28K8j.png)
i'm writting this code

```
class Solution {
    public int removeElement(int[] nums, int val) {
        int k =0;
         int[] expectedNums = new int[nums.length]; 
            for(int i =0,j=0; i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]==val)
    k++;
    else{
    expectedNums[j]=nums[i];
    j++;}
    }
     for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++){
    nums[i]=expectedNums[i];}
    for (int a = 0; a < nums.length; a++) {
        System.out.print( nums[a]);}
    
        return k;
    }
    
}
```

problem 27 in leetcode, as you can see in the screenshot, the output only shows first 2 elements then skips 2 elements, while the actual output is not. System.out.print shows that its 01304000. Leetcode output shows [0,1,3]. I know there is a much easier solution, and i wanna use it, but first i must know what's wrong with this code? i'm new to leetcode, maybe copying lists and arrays here is not supported? Idk fr Please help thanks

Tried using ArrayList, changing

```
for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++){
    nums[i]=expectedNums[i];}
```

length a lot. thought it was the issue.
Also Rewrote the code again and made sure nothing is limiting the array as fas as i know.
I didn't directly change nums array elements, only copy.

Comment: For reference, LeetCode 27 is at https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/

Comment: Images of text, including example input, example expected output, example actual output, code, and error messages are [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here. Such information should be in the question body. To ensure accuracy, using text copy-and-paste is advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be confusion about what the LeetCode problem is asking the programmer to do. This is an example of why a link to the problem page included in the question body is helpful, when the source of the problem does have a page. This is typical of the programming challenge sites. (However, some of these sites require an account to see their problems.)

- The `int` value, `k`, in the O/P code is the number of elements that were *removed* from the `nums` array. **This is where the bug is.** The value returned is supposed to be the number of elements that *remain* after the targeted values were removed.
- LeetCode asks this problem be solved **in-place**. The expected solutions *do not* create an intermediate array, or other structures to temporarily hold data. Although the code in the question seems to have gotten away with it, this line `int[] expectedNums = new int[nums.length];` violates that constraint.
- I notice that the code in the question has a variable `expectedNums`. The automated judge described in the problem page also uses a variable with this same name. That hints that there might be another misunderstanding. The solution code is not expected to have a variable `expectedNums`. It is allowed to. But, if it does, the variable will be unrelated to the `expectedNums` in the code for the judge.
- The description of the automated judge can be used to help design a solution to the given problem.

I don't want to give the O/P an answer with complete code. I believe it will be more helpful if the O/P spends time thinking about how to solve this.

- Bear in mind that the automated judge will sort the first `k` elements of `nums` array after the `removeElement` method is called. In Java, that would be `nums[0]` to `nums[k - 1]`.
- The automated judge *doesn't care* what is `nums [k]` to `nums [nums.length - 1]`.

Comment: Seems to be a misunderstanding from me, i never thought they would use k as the length of the answer, my English isn't excellent at all. Changing the value returned from "k" to ```k-nums.length``` solved the problem for me and it works like a charm now. Thanks You so much.